# Sorting dictionaries in python by values that are actually lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

If I'm given a dictionary to represent a graph, where vertices are keys and values are lists, whose entries contain both a neighbor vertex and the weight between the two vertices, how can I return a list of edges in increasing order with no repeats? For example, I may be given the following dictionary...:

> {"A": [["B",10], ["D",5]], "B": [["A",10], ["C",5]], "C": [["B",5],["D",15]], "D": [["C",15], ["A",5]]}.

Also I'm only allowed to import the copy library, so I could copy one list and use deepcopy() to create a new object with the same elements.

Right now, I'm trying to turn the dictionary into a list, because I figure it might be easier to sort elements within a list, and delete duplicate edges. So at the moment I have the following (graph is the dictionary, and in this case the one I provided above)...

```
def edge_get(graph):

    input_list = []
    sorted_list = []

    for key, value in graph.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        input_list.append(temp)

    print(input_list)
```

This prints out...

> [['A', [['B', 10], ['D', 5]]], ['B', [['A', 10], ['C', 5]]], ['C', [['B', 5], ['D', 15]]], ['D', [['C', 15], ['A', 5]]]]

I would like to get it to output:

> [['A', 'B', 10], ['A', 'D', 5], ['B', 'A', 10], ['B', 'C', 5],...

I figure if I can get it like this, I can compare the third element of each list, within the list, and if they are the same, check to see if the other elements match (same edge). And based off of that I can add it to the final list or forget it and move on.

For this example the ultimate goal is:

> [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]

Answer (score 3):

So you have a dict that represents a graph as adjacency list, and you want to convert that adjacency list into an edge list.

You can do that with a nested list comprehension:

```
graph = {"A": [["B",10], ["D",5]], "B": [["A",10], ["C",5]], "C": [["B",5],["D",15]], "D": [["C",15], ["A",5]]}
edges = [(src, dst, weight) for src, adjs in graph.items() for dst, weight in adjs]
# edges = [('A', 'B', 10), ('A', 'D', 5), ('B', 'A', 10), ('B', 'C', 5), ('C', 'B', 5), ('C', 'D', 15), ('D', 'C', 15), ('D', 'A', 5)]
```

Then you can eliminate duplicates edges by converting to a dict, note that if you have duplicate edges with conflicting weights, this will pick one of the weight arbitrarily:

```
uniques = {frozenset([src, dst]): weight for src, dst, weight in edges}
# uniques = {frozenset({'B', 'A'}): 10, frozenset({'A', 'D'}): 5, frozenset({'B', 'C'}): 5, frozenset({'C', 'D'}): 15}
```

and then sort the edges with sorted:

```
sorted_uniques = sorted(uniques.items(), key=lambda v: v[1])
# sorted_uniques = [(frozenset({'A', 'D'}), 5), (frozenset({'C', 'B'}), 5), (frozenset({'A', 'B'}), 10), (frozenset({'C', 'D'}), 15)]
```

Finally, to get the result in the structure you wanted, you simply do:

```
result = [sorted(e) for e, weight in sorted_uniques]
# result = [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the combinations of key with each related sublist. If you sort and unpack the string components of each combination, then you get the initial output you are looking for. From there you can sort the entire list first by the weight value and then by the vertices in order to get an ordered list. If you slice that list with a step value you can remove the duplicates. Then you can just remove the weight value to get the list of pairs for your final output.

You could consolidate the steps below just a bit more but this goes through the steps outlined in your question to hopefully make it a bit easier to follow.

```
from itertools import product
from operator import itemgetter

d = {"A": [["B",10], ["D",5]], "B": [["A",10], ["C",5]], "C": [["B",5],["D",15]], "D": [["C",15], ["A",5]]}

combos = [[*sorted([c1, c2]), n] for k, v in d.items() for c1, [c2, n] in product(k, v)]
print(combos)
# [['A', 'B', 10], ['A', 'D', 5], ['A', 'B', 10], ['B', 'C', 5], ['B', 'C', 5], ['C', 'D', 15], ['C', 'D', 15], ['A', 'D', 5]]

ordered = sorted(combos, key=itemgetter(2, 0, 1))[::2]
print(ordered)
# [['A', 'D', 5], ['B', 'C', 5], ['A', 'B', 10], ['C', 'D', 15]]

pairs = [o[:-1] for o in ordered]
print(pairs)
# [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```

EDIT (without imports):

Per comment highlighting a restriction on using imports in your solution, here is a modified version of the original. Differences are replacement of `itertools.product` with list comprehension that accomplishes the same thing and the replacement of `operator.itemgetter` with a lambda.

```
d = {"A": [["B",10], ["D",5]], "B": [["A",10], ["C",5]], "C": [["B",5],["D",15]], "D": [["C",15], ["A",5]]}

combos = [[*sorted([k, c]), n] for k, v in d.items() for c, n in v]
print(combos)
# [['A', 'B', 10], ['A', 'D', 5], ['A', 'B', 10], ['B', 'C', 5], ['B', 'C', 5], ['C', 'D', 15], ['C', 'D', 15], ['A', 'D', 5]]

ordered = sorted(combos, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0], x[1]))[::2]
print(ordered)
# [['A', 'D', 5], ['B', 'C', 5], ['A', 'B', 10], ['C', 'D', 15]]

pairs = [o[:-1] for o in ordered]
print(pairs)
# [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```

Comment: OP isn’t allowed to `import`.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent each edge as `frozenset` and filter edge duplicates with help of `set`:

```
G = {"A": [["B",10], ["D",5]], "B": [["A",10], ["C",5]], "C": [["B",5],["D",15]], "D": [["C",15], ["A",5]]}

edges = {(frozenset((k, i)), j) for k, v in G.items()
                                for i, j in v}
[sorted(i) for i, _ in sorted(edges, key=lambda x: x[1])]
# [['B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```